# How to combine two actions to a single shortcut with dconf

Tags: debian, ubuntu, gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, dconf

I currently store all my windows management shortcuts in a github repo and then any time I'm on a new machine, instance, VM, etc then I can clone the repo and use

```
dconf load /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/ < dconf_shortcuts_backup
```

to load all my shortcuts.

The problem I have is that I can only assign one shortcut to one action e.g.,

```
move-to-side-w=['<ctrl>h']
maximize-vertically=['<ctrl><super>k']
```

However, I would like to combine two actions to one shortcut e.g., perform `move-to-side-w` and then perform `maximize-vertically` when `['<ctrl>h']` is pushed. Can anyone help me do this?

I don't know if my choice of Google search phrase is bad but I only seem to find information on having multiple shortcuts to one action and not multiple actions to one shortcut like this https://superuser.com/questions/409843/add-more-than-one-keyboard-shortcut-for-an-action-in-gnome

I'm using Ubuntu 20 LTS with GNOME 3.36.8